# Using SUMIFS formula where I need to SUM Negative Values as Well

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to SUM values with SUMIFS formula but i also want to SUM negative values available in the range `B2:B15`. Where formula will ignore its `-` sign and sum them.

Lets suppose

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B15,A2:A15,F2,C2:C15,">="&F1,C2:C15,"<="&G1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ABS` and `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$19=F2)*ABS($C$2:$C$19))
```

[image]

If your version of Excel supports `FILTER`, you can use:

```
=SUM(ABS(FILTER($C$2:$C$19,$B$2:$B$19=F2)))
```

Comment: I am stuck on this how to convert this for ABS `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Transactions[Square_Amount],Transactions[Payment_Id],Orders[Payment_Id])*(Orders[Restaurant_Name]=A3))` @BigBen can you please look at it. Here is the amount that will be summed up `Transactions[Square_Amount]` i did it like `ABS(Transactions[Square_Amount])`

Comment: What is the original `SUMIFS`, w/o the changes you've tried?

Comment: Original is working now but have to change this as well

Answer (score 0):

If u r a MS365 user u will use UNIQUE formula to get USA and Germany first. Or else remove duplicate from the DATA menu will do wonder for you. If u want that part i.e. extraction of unique countries and that too without the latest UNIQUE function u will need to roll ur head a bit. U can however achieve the same with FREQUENCY MATCH combo to get to the Unique records. below is the link to refer to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBo4Wz-TPT4

Now coming to ur summation part.
$b$2:$B$19=$F$2 will return a string of true false. True for uSA.So u will multiply these with ABS($C$2:$C$19). SO this will be like TRUE*586,TRUE*9854............FALSE*586....
TRUE and FALSE in Boolean Mathematics is reckoned as 1 and 0.
so,
($b$2:$B$19=$F$2)*ABS($C$2:$C$19). Now find its sum
1.
sum(($b$2:$B$19=$F$2)*ABS($C$2:$C$19))  Confirm with Control Shift Enter
2. SUMPRODUCT(($b$2:$B$19=$F$2)*ABS($C$2:$C$19)) Confirm with ENTER