# Want to Convert SUMIFS to SUMPRODUCT for using ABS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have been using this formula to get the SUM of this Range `Sheet2!D2:D30` and it is working fine.

I want to add now ABS function to SUM the negative value from this Range `Sheet2!D2:D30` and i tried with below formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D30,Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30)*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3))
```

I added the ABS but its not working any help will be appreciated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(ABS(Sheet2!D2:D30),Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30)*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3))
```

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Sheet3

[image]

Comment: The Q&A here shows what you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67385050/4961700

Comment: Ok let me explain: I have been matching the `Sheet2 ID's` with `Sheet1 ID's` then Matching `Sheet1 County` with `Sheet3 Country` to Paste `Sheet2` values in `Sheet3`

Comment: Are the id's in sheet2 column I unique? no duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are unique ID's in Sheet 2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D30,Sheet2!I2:I30,Sheet1!I2:I30))*(Sheet1!D2:D30=A3))
```

Comment: Can you please give me one more favor that i want to add Date Column as well in this formula @Scott Craner if you could help. Sheet2!B2:B1000,">="&$F$1,Sheet2!B2:B1000,"<="&$G$1

Comment: What happens when you put those as conditions in the SUMIFS?

Comment: OMG it worked i was thinking there must be another way to do this but your comment guides me the way. Thank you